# Touch screen not working

Tags: touchscreen

I cracked the screen on my android A13 Allwinner tablet so I got new screen and put it on the tablet but the touch screen is not working at all. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't fit the new screen correctly. That's something that can only be fixed with physical access to the device.

Comment: It doesn't do just to "put it on". You also need to take care for the contacts etc. to be connected properly. If you're not sure on what should be done where, it might be a good idea to use a service which does.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help:

fix digitizer issues - Google-Suche
https://www.google.de/search?q=fix+digitizer+issues

Possible fix for digitizer/touch screen issues - xda-developers
http ://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1459569

[Resolved] Touch screen/digitizer issues (random inputs/not accepting touch input) - Android Forums
http ://androidforums.com/htc-one/728735-resolved-touch-screen-digitizer-issues-random-inputs-not-accepting-touch-input.html

Fix digitizer problems yourself
http ://www.thoracic.org/education/mobile-musings/articles/August-2006.php